# Common generic Type between Class and interface

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface as below

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {

    List<String> method1(T data);

    boolean method2(T data);
}
```

And I have another class as below

```
public class SomeClass<T>{
    private final String id;
    private final T record;
}
```

Is there a way to have a common/same generic (Type T) between the interface and the class ?

Comment: What do you mean by "common"? A type that would expose both the methods of `SomeInterface` and `SomeClass`?

Comment: Sure.  Write a class that holds them both and uses the same type parameter.  `class SomeInterfaceAndClass<T> { private final SomeInterface<T> someInterface; private final SomeClass<T> someClass; }`

Comment: Yes that would work. Thank you. I wish there was a way to mark this correct answer :)